# Extract text from illustrator file without opening file

Tags: automation, applescript, adobe-illustrator

Any idea if it would be possible to extract text from a illustrator file without opening it?

I have an AppleScript currently extracting the text but it takes a long time when I'm working on hundreds of files. I was wondering if it would be possible to get the information without opening the AI file.

Comment: Can you please post the AppleScript (or relevant portions of it), and also give details of what text you want retrieved ?

Comment: See my comment on "has" reply. What I'm trying to do is getting the text of the text frames without opening the illustrator file. I guess I would need to parse the binary file.

Comment: I wonder if there is any File Format Specification for .AI files like there's one for .PSD (http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm), I couldn't find one tho.

Comment: I viewed the contents a random .AI file in the command line using `cat` and, being a binary file, obviously contains a lot of junk.  But it does contain some readable text as well.  So your best bet is to use a `do shell script` command in AppleScript in order to get the contents of the file in text format, then filter it for the lines that you need.  Provided you can devise an adequate filter (hence why I asked what text you needed), this should take a few microseconds to run.

Comment: Hi CJK, thanks for your reply, however this is untrue. The only data you can see is the xmpdata which contains metadata about the file (creation, .psd linked, Producer, Version... exct) but it doesn't contain the text of the text frames inside the .AI file.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for show your own code first. (Also, typo in first line: I think you meant “Illustrator”, not “photoshop”.)

If you’re only getting plain text it should only take a fraction of a second per document (opening the file will take longer):

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    get contents of every text frame of document 1
end tell
```

(i.e. Never iterate over individual application objects, querying each one, when a single query will do everything for you. Apple events are relatively expensive for apps to resolve; sending lots of them unnecessarily really kills performance.)

Also be aware that AppleScript also has serious performance problems when iterating over large lists, but that’s a separate issue, the solution to which should already be covered elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, typo mistake thanks! Well, you wrote what I'm already doing, I'm extracting the text of every text frame for a list of .ai files I give to my AppleScript, I use the following to get text of each text frame: set the_text to the contents of text_frame

Comment: Again, update your post to show [the relevant portion of] your current script so we can actually see and test it ourselves.